# How to remove unwanted counting-increment from forEach method?

Tags: javascript, events, indexing, foreach, increment

I'm having a trouble to get rid of unwanted counting-increment from `forEach` method in my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/BeZEjX).

The algorithm is simple:

1. `EventManager()` registers an event called `mouseenter` to every each of `menuCells`.
2. `menuCount()` gets an current `index` of the targeted cell. Next, matches it between a new node's `index` for showing or hiding a `slateCell`.
3. `slateCount()` gets the targeted `item` from the `menuCount()`, and using `forEach()` for getting `li`'s index.

The problem is every time when I **restart the event**, an increment of the `forEach()` itself is increasing time to time like this: (couldn't imagine better describing words. Limited vocabulary problem :|)

[image]

This may not be a big problem because what the function does is actually just getting an index. But since I noticed this was abnormal, I wanted to know why and how to get rid of that unwanted increment counting.

I've been trying to find how to resolve my case or such as mine but still haven't found any of infos or articles.

Are there any solutions to fix this problem?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/BeZEjX)

```js
'use strict';
const Slater = (function() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.menu'),
      slate = document.querySelector('.slate');

  let node_menuCells = menu.querySelectorAll('.cell'),
      node_slateCells = slate.querySelectorAll('.grid.first > .cell');

  let menuCells = Array.from(node_menuCells);
  
  function EventManager(array, node) {
    array.reduce((init, length, current) => {
      node[current].addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => menuCount(e, current, node_slateCells));
    }, 0);
  }
  function menuCount(event, index, node) {
    console.log(`menuCell count is: ${index}`);
    node.forEach((item, i) => {
      let comparing = (i == index) ? item.classList.add('shown') : item.classList.remove('shown');
      slateCount(item);
    })
  }
  function slateCount(item) {
    let node_cellItems = item.querySelectorAll('li');
    node_cellItems.forEach((listItem, n) => {
      listItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        console.log(`slateCell count is: ${n}`);
      })
    })
  }
  return {
    initialize: EventManager(menuCells, node_menuCells)
  }
}());
```

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
      }
      ul li {
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 20px 0;
      }
      .layout {
        width: 900px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #414141;
      }
      .menu {
        height: 60px;
      }
      .cell {
        
        margin: 0 20px;
        font-family:'Helvetica';
      }
      .slate {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(160, 117, 0);
        height: 20rem;
      }
      .grid {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid rgb(160, 117, 0);
      }
      .grid > .cell {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        color: rgb(36, 88, 21);
      }
      .shown {
        display: block !important;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="menu layout">
      <div class="cell">Lorem</div>
      <div class="cell">Ipsum Dolor</div>
      <div class="cell">Consectetur</div>
      <div class="cell">Similique</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slate layout">
      <div class="grid first">
        <ul class="cell">
          <li>Sample Text 001</li>
          <li>Sample Text 002</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cell">
          <li>Sample Text 003</li>
          <li>Sample Text 004</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="grid second">
        <ul class="cell">
          <li>Sample Text 001</li>
          <li>Sample Text 002</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="cell">
          <li>Sample Text 003</li>
          <li>Sample Text 004</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, every time you hover the top menu, a for-loop is ran to add event listeners on the slate items. So if you hover the slate items for the first time, the behavior is the same as you would expect, logging just once. However, if you repeat the action of hovering the menu, more and more of the same event listeners will be added to the slate items, so the log starts to blow up quickly, causing memory leaks.

To solve this, extract the logic of adding event listeners into the init function so that it will only be executed once.

```
function EventManager(array, node) {
    array.reduce((init, length, current) => {
        node[current].addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => menuCount(e, current, node_slateCells));
    }, 0);

    // add the event listeners here
    node_slateCells.forEach(item => slateCount(item));
}

function menuCount(event, index, node) {
    console.log(`menuCell count is: ${index}`);
    node.forEach((item, i) => {
        let comparing = (i == index) ? item.classList.add('shown') : item.classList.remove('shown');
        // slateCount(item);
    })
}

function slateCount(item) {
    let node_cellItems = item.querySelectorAll('li');
    node_cellItems.forEach((listItem, n) => {
        listItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
            console.log(`slateCell count is: ${n}`);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Dang it, couldn't imagine how simple the solution was, and thank you for helping organize my question.